# Chrome: window.print vs ctrl + p

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I have a internet project where users print a lot. So we add "print button" in every page.

It work's fine in all browser, but google chrome.

This button just call "javacript:window.print". But when pressed, chrome opens new tab "chrome://print" just like when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is typed.

But with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> print preview is showed fine.
With "window.print" we get this message: "*Print is unavailable because the page you were trying to print has been closed.*"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a test case? It seems to work fine on http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/V8nWZ/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add a "return false;" to the button to prevent the default action. So it opens the new tab, but keep the old one at the previous state.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't think this before! thank you!